# bash tab completion not working in graphical shells

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a fresh install of xubuntu 14.04 with xrdp installed.

- tab completion works when logged in via ssh
- tab completion doesn't work when using any graphical shell (terminal, xterm, ...)
- `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` is there
- dot-sourcing that file doesn't help, too, in graphical shells
- `/bin/bash` is the default shell and is also returned by `echo $SHELL`
- the usual lines in .bashrc are there

those are the lines in .bashrc (for every user on the system - it's actually also in the skeleton file in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`):

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

What else could cause the tab completion to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1771058&p=11107297#post11107297).

It's xfce what's blocking the use of tab.

edit `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`

find this line:
`<property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="string" value="switch_window_key"/>`

NOTE: there can be multiple lines containing `name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab"`, so keep searching until you find the one also containing the `value="switch_window_key"`.

and change it to:
`<!--<property name="&lt;Super&gt;Tab" type="string" value="switch_window_key"/>-->`

Relog.